# How can we customize order of count,avg,sum,min and max in DoubleSummaryStatistics object in java8

Tags: java, java-8

I am getting below output in following format, which is default I think.

```
{"count":100,"sum":25640.13,"min":2.65,"max":483.91,"average":256.4013}
```

But I want to change this format as below.

```
{"sum":"25640.13","avg":"256.40","max":"483.91","min":"2.65","count":100}
```

Below code I am using in java class.

```
 @Override
public DoubleSummaryStatistics getStatistic() {
    logger.info("Getting statistic");
    Set<Entry<Long, Transaction>> endtrySet = statisticHistory.entrySet();
    List<Double> amountList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Entry<Long, Transaction> entry : endtrySet) {
        if (((entry.getValue().getDate())).isAfter(Instant.now().minusSeconds(windowInMs)))
            amountList.add((entry.getValue().getAmount()).doubleValue());
    }
    return amountList.stream().mapToDouble((x) -> x).summaryStatistics();

}
```

How can I rearrange the json format?

For more understanding, pasting above method with simple syntax.
Sample Code Method..

```
    public DoubleSummaryStatistics getStatisdtic() {
    logger.info("Getting statistic");
    Set<BigDecimal> endtrySet = null ; //= getting this from a other resource
    List<Double> amountList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (BigDecimal entry : endtrySet) {
            amountList.add((entry).doubleValue());
    }
    return amountList.stream().mapToDouble((x) -> x).summaryStatistics();

}
```

Comment: how about serializing a *new* Object in the order that you need? You can't place your own annotations on the `DoubleSummaryStatistics`...

Comment: this is implementation of my Interface which has this method so I placed @Override annotation(Is this annotation you are taking about?)

Comment: but than, why would you "care" about this order to begin with? isn't your UI code when deserializing suppose to call a getter anyway and build whatever output it wants in whatever order?

Comment: It is a Implementation of micro-service, I have to send specified format only.

Comment: I want to run a script, which have test cases with that json format and it is failing due to this

Comment: in such case why not create a view object, like `MyDoubleSummaryStatistics` and build it from your `DoubleSummaryStatistics` result the way you want to in whatever order of the fields?

Comment: @Eugene Let me try this, It should work in that case.

Comment: Aren’t your tests too strict then? Wouldn’t it be enough to test that all the fields are there and have the correct contents?

Comment: @Eugene, Yes it is working by adding additional class. Thanks

Comment: in such a case, you think that it would be appropriate for me to post such an answer? can't tell if I should or not... :|

Comment: Sure, why not !

Comment: @Eugene, I think you should so that other will get  to know, because generally programmer look at answer first than comment.

Comment: What are you doing in your test case? Are you calling `toString()` on the summary statistics value? There's nothing in your code about JSON, I wonder if what you are seeing is actually the `toString()` representation.

Comment: If you are trying to test a `DoubleSummaryStatistics` instance, as the return type for your `getStatistic()` method suggests, then you could just test the `count`, `sum` and so on individually and avoid this whole problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't edit `DoubleSummaryStatistics` (you can't add your own json specific annotations inside it), the thing you can do is create your own class `MyDoubleSummaryStatistics` that would be created from whatever result you want.

But in case you are calling `toString` on that `DoubleSummaryStatistics`, why not call each field separately from it, like `DoubleSummaryStatistics ::getAverage` and the like and build whatever string you need/want.

Comment: Well, you could use [Jackson's mixing annotations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations).

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I thought about that, but *I would not do that*, point on *I*